# Block traffic to server based on known bad hosts list

Tags: networking, ubuntu, security

there used to be a project like denyhosts that would block bad ips from reaching your server but as far as i understand that is now dead? https://askubuntu.com/questions/433924/package-denyhosts-in-ubuntu-trusty-tahr-is-deleted-temporary-or-forever

Is there anything else like this? I primarily want to block traffic to my nginx server because SSH is already limited to my static ip.

Comment: The question that you link to has several good answers, including the use of `iptables` or `fail2ban`.  Is there some reason why those answers do not work for you?

Comment: I already use fail2ban for ssh just in case the ip filter would not work for some reason and the iptables solutions i found are all static. denyhosts would update it self automatically and was a set it and forget it solution.

Comment: Also, fail2ban won't really work for my nginx setup without a looot of configuration as i have an access/error log per site spread out all over the disk.

Comment: It looks like DenyHosts is no longer dead: http://denyhost.sourceforge.net/CHANGELOG.txt  You could download and install the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`denyhosts` was dead: after the version 2.6 (Dec 7, 2006), there were no updates for six years.  It is, however, now alive.  It has had two releases in 2014.  The changelog is [here](http://denyhost.sourceforge.net/CHANGELOG.txt).  You can download the latest version from [here](http://denyhost.sourceforge.net/download.php).